# python process creating file with inflated size

Tags: python, json

i have a python process which takes a file containing streamed data and converts it into a format ready to load to a database. i have just migrated this process from one Linux GCP VM to another running exactly the same code, but the final output file size is nearly 4 times as big. 500mb vs 2gb.

When i download the files and manually inspect them, they look exactly the same to the eye.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Edit: Thanks for the feedback, i traced it back to the input file, which is slightly different (as my stream recording process has also been migrated)

I am now trying to work out why a marginally different file creates such a different output file once its been processed.

Comment: I suspect the file has lots of blocks of `0`, and one of the systems is optimizing these blocks, the other isn't. Maybe you have different filesystem types.

Comment: Its hard to explain such a large difference, but different default string encodings could be part of it. For instance, ascii strings in utf-32 are 4 times as large.

Comment: the op does not say which is the output format, but if it is a pickle file, that may well be the case.